# When should I use serialization library in boost

Tags: c++, boost

Recently, I found boost's serialization library. But when I use it to save my data to file, I found that this library is not what I expected to be.
Because I'm not using interface ISerializable and implement the methods save and load of that interface. But instead, I should add friend class, and implement function template. Personally, I think it's ugly ( although the design idea may be some kind of nice and tricky). And when I try to store 2 points into a text file, I get a file like this:
[image]

Obviously it's hard for human to read.
So my question is:
1. In what kind of situation should I use this library to do serialization work. For example, should I use it just to store some 3D points into a file? Or should I use it in more complex scenarios.
2. Is there any way for me to control the format of the output file? Because I think the figure above is really hard to understand.

Comment: Serialization is not intended for humans to understand. If they can understand it, that's fine but it probably means the format is not as efficient as it could be. You use serialization when you want to transfer data in a format that allows it to be reconstructed without concern for underlying hardware differences like sizes of values or byte ordering.

Comment: @mah Thanks, so its main purpose is the data portability?

Comment: Yes, that's a good way to summarize it. Object storage is also a good use case for serialization.

Comment: We use Boost.Serialization a lot, the XML archive is nice for debugging and quite readable, the binary archive is efficient. Have you tried using the XML archive if you are concerned about readability?

Comment: It *is* possible to serialize in human-readable formats. XML is sort of human readable and you can serialize to XML with boost. You can also define your own formats and make them as cryptic or transparent as you want.